# Как исправить ошибку distutils.core в Python3.7?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm

Пайчарм на Ubuntu Server 18.04 при настройке нового venv на основе python 3.7 ругается на отсутствие distutils.core, в гугле пишут про то, что `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`, но это бесполезно, так как:

```
u@u:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет python3-distutils самой новой версии (3.6.5-3).
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
u@u:~$ sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Заметьте, вместо «python3.7-distutils» выбирается «python3-distutils»
Уже установлен пакет python3-distutils самой новой версии (3.6.5-3).
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Давайте начнём сначала: откуда у вас Python 3.7?

Comment: @andreymal sudo apt-get install python3.7, из репозитория ubuntu bionic.

Comment: Странно, пакет python3-distutils предоставляет себя и для питона 3.7 тоже, по идее всё должно работать. Завтра попробую воспроизвести проблему у себя, а вам я пока советую на всякий случай уточнить, о какой именно «настройке нового venv» идёт речь (даже в пределах pycharm есть много всяких разных вариантов манипуляций с venv)

Comment: @andreymal [скриншот](https://pp.userapi.com/c850636/v850636573/10950/jnt6Xp5XoeA.jpg)

Comment: @YardalGedal, на скриншоте же видно, что используется не системный питон, а какой-то свой в `~/v4/env/bin/python`... т.е. придётся или для него ставить distutils (сторонними средствами) или использовать системный... хотя возможно я что-то не так понял...

Comment: @Fat-Zer в системном возникает та же ошибка.

Comment: @YardalGedal, системный — `python3`? а **не** `/usr/bin/python`, который по старой доброй традиции всё ещё ссылка на `python2`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я имел в виду системный Python 3.7, который в /usr/bin/python3.7.

Comment: @YardalGedal, а из консоли `import distutils.core` нормально отрабатывает? если да, то я бы поискал, может где-ещё в настройках не верный путь к интерпретатору может быть указан... не вижу других возможных причин подобного поведения, если честно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer distutils импортируется, distutils.core - нет.

Comment: @YardalGedal, странно... а `/usr/lib/python3.{6,7}/distutils/core.py` на месте? попробуй `apt-get install --reinstall python3-distutils` — может файлы после изначальной установки были повреждены...

Comment: Завтра у меня немножко затянулось, но я сейчас проверил в своей Ubuntu 18.04 с PyCharm Community 2018.2 — всё создалось https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBsET.png